# MVC 5 UserManager.FindAsync throwing error when deployed on azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, usermanager

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 website that connects to a remote sql database.

The website works fine when it's running from the visual studio iis express.

However, when i deploy the website on azurewebsites and attach the debugger on the login function, i see that the UserManager.FindAsync function redirects me to the general error view page.

This is where the UserManager checks if user exists:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

And this is the web.config connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=87.87.87.87,1433;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=False; User Id=username; password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This website works when it's deployed elsewhere as well.

The problem occurs when it's deployed on azurewebsites.

Comment: Can you post the exception/stack trace that is being throwing on Azure?

Comment: Also, it is a good idea to turn off all custom errors while troubleshooting an issue (like in `<customErrors mode="Off">`

Comment: did you find an answer? facing the same issue